# Влияние частицы "это" на постановку запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Ср: "Что ты, без выходных?" и "Что это ты без выходных?"

Почему в первом случае запятая ставится, а во втором опускается?

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что второй пример не может быть произнесён с интонацией, требующей постановки запятой (или какого-либо другого знака)?

Comment: Солидарна с Вами, _Слава._ В первом случае пунктуация тоже не бесспорна — все зависит от контекста. А его-то и нет!

Answer (score 1):

Эти два вопроса имеют *разный смысл*, что сказывается на интонации и на пунктуации (и наоборот, воспринимаемый смысл может следовать из того или другого).
Первый вопрос требует *подтверждения/опровержения* предполагаемого *факта* (в качестве ответа; "**так ли** это?"):

> -- Что ты [= Ты что], без выходных? - Да, без выходных.

Во втором вопросе факт известен (напр. человек вместо своего выходного пришёл на работу), а спрашивают о *причине* наблюдаемого факта (что это = почему /это/; "**почему** это так?"):

> -- Что это ты без выходных? - Очень захотелось поработать.

"**Это**" указывает здесь на наблюдаемый факт (ситуацию), о причине которого спрашивают.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен.
Отвечаю строго на заданный вопрос: **Как влияет частица ЭТО на постановку запятой?**

1) Усилительная частица ЭТО **не влияет на постановку запятой непосредственно**. При ее наличии (как и  при ее отсутствии) предложение может иметь варианты (с запятой и без запятой):

(1) Что это ты без выходных?  (Почему ты без выходных?).

(2) Что это ты, без выходных? Что ты, без выходных? (Ты без выходных?).

2) Однако  при наличии частицы ЭТО **чаще встречается обычный вариант вопросительного предложения**: **Что это ты** стал заботиться о порядке?  [Фазиль Искандер. Должники (1968)]

3) В некоторых случаях без частицы ЭТО возможен только один вариант:  ***Что ты, без выходных?*** Семантика второго варианта в этом случае (Что ты без выходных?) неясно воспринимается.

**Примечание**

Вариант с запятой - это тема вопросительно-восклицательных слов, которая рассмотрена у Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129

Comment: Возможны варианты с другими (кроме что и как) словами? Почему ты, не хочешь что ли идти с нами?

Comment: Все варианты: (1) Ты что,  без выходных? Ты что это,  без выходных? (2) Ты что это без выходных?

Comment: Не думаю, что это **все** варианты. Возможна и постановка тире, например, в такой ситуации. _Кому интересно, что ты работаешь на износ? **Что ты — без выходных?**_ Поэтому я и написала, что нужен контекст. А то в своих предположениях мы последние перья изломаем.

Comment: Думаю, что ломать перья не стоит, просто надо отвечать на тот, вопрос, который участник Владимир задал. К примеру, про тире он не спрашивал. Если начинаешь что-то дополнительно объяснять, только хуже получается. У меня, например, никогда не получается, как будто на разных языках говорим.

Comment: @Aer !!! НЕ ПОЛУЧАЮ ответных сообщений, мне адресованных, — как сегодня (прошло восемь часов!). Говорю об этом уже не первый раз.